# Flag -deprecatedrpc=addressess - Bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, taproot

How long do we will have the `-deprecatedrpc=addressess` flag for Bitcoin core. Is it just for the v22.0 or will it be available for all minor and patch releases until v23.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, deprecated RPCs are available for one major release. That would mean this specific one will not be present in Bitcoin Core 23.0 anymore, but will be in any 22.x releases.

Comment: Thank you so much, Pieter!